# Drupal7 REST: I am not able to perform POST and PUT methods. Error is :Not Acceptable : Node type is required, Code:406?

Tags: rest, http, drupal, drupal-7, httprequest

I'm using drupal7. my drupal_http_request() for get and delete are working fine for authenticated users, but the post and put methods are not working.

The error is `:Not Acceptable : Node type is required`, and http error code is `:406`. My code is below:

```
function ws_form_post_auth() {

$base_url = 'http://localhost/drupalws/api/v1';
$data = array(
  'username' => 'student1',
  'password' => 'welcome',
);
$data = http_build_query($data, '', '&');
$options = array(
  'headers' => array(
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
  ),
  'method' => 'POST',
  'data' => $data
);

$response = drupal_http_request($base_url . '/user/login', $options);
$data = json_decode($response->data);

// Check if login was successful
if ($response->code == 200) {

    $options['headers']['Cookie'] = $data->session_name . '=' . $data->sessid;
    $options['headers']['X-CSRF-Token'] = $data->token;

    $data = array(
        'title' => 'First forum post',
        'type'=> 'forum',
        'body'=> array(
            'und'=>array(
                0=> array(
                    'value'=>'This is my first forum post via httprequest.'
                )
            )
        )
    );
  $data = json_encode($data);

  $options['data'] = $data;
  $options['method'] = 'POST';

  $response = drupal_http_request($base_url . '/node', $options);

  return $response->status_message;
}
return $response->status_message;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution for my issue,I just missed a Content-Type in Headers.

[....]
if ($response->code == 200) {

```
$options['headers']['Cookie'] = $data->session_name . '=' . $data->sessid;
$options['headers']['X-CSRF-Token'] = $data->token;
$options['headers']['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
```

[....]